# Dozer Boolean mapping Eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mapping, dozer

I am using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to map objects. But I am getting an wired error message

> Property active for class com.edfx.adb.persist.entity.Customer cannot
> be read from.

in the Dozer Mapping Editor of Eclipse, I have Dozer plugin installed in Eclipse. This is the mapping I have:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.edfx.adb.persist.entity.Customer</class-a>
    <class-b>com.edfx.adb.web.dto.CustomerDTO</class-b>

    <field>
        <a get-method="isActive">active</a>
        <b get-method="isActive">active</b>
        <a-hint>java.lang.Boolean</a-hint>
        <b-hint>java.lang.Boolean</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Here `active` is the field with type `boolean` in `Customer` and `CustomerDTO` class.

I am unable to remove or hide the error message. Also don't know why it is showing. And for this error Eclipse showing error in whole project which is undesirable.

Any information would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting hints. In this scenario I think you don´t need them. 
But for best solution can you post your code for the entity and the DTO.